# Checking for multilpe keys in dict

Tags: python

I have a dict() like so,

```
xyz = {"a":{"b":[1,2,3]}}
```

I want to check to see if the nested dict has a key of "b" or "c".
I can check one key like,

```
>>> "b" in xyz.get("a",{})
True
```

Ive tried the following,

```
>>> "b" or "c" in xyz.get("a",{})
'b'
```

But wanted to know if I can write this statement for both "b" and "c".
Hope this makes sense.

Comment: `or` doesn't work like that; this may be the most commonly asked Python question on StackOverflow. You could just do `"b" in xyz.get("a", {}) or "c" in xyz.get("a", {})`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`or` doesn't work like that. (This may be the most commonly asked Python question on StackOverflow, but unfortunately it's very hard to search for unless you already know what the problem is...) `or` just takes two Boolean expressions and returns something truthy if either of them are truthy So what you're asking for is whether `"b"` is truthy (it is), or `"c" in xyz.get("a", {})` is truthy (it may or may not be, but Python doesn't even have to check), so it gives you back `"b"`, which is truthy.

You might thing you could fix that with parentheses, `("b" or "c") in xyz.get("a", {})`, but that's just as bad. First it'll evaluate `("b" or "c")` and get `"b"`, then it'll check whether that's in the dict, ignoring `"c"`.

The reason the equivalent sentence sort of makes sense in English is that you're implicitly asking "is b in the dict or c in the dict"; Python won't let you leave that implicit, but you can always make it explicit:

```
"b" in xyz.get("a", {}) or "c" in xyz.get("a", {})`
```

If you want to do more than 2 of these (or if they're only known dynamically), then you'll want to use `any`, and/or store `xyz.get("a", {})` in a temporary variable instead of repeating it, as in utdemir's answer--or, maybe even better, using a set, as in Kasra's answer.

Comment: In this case its faster solution! but for more values its not a good choice!

Comment: @Kasra: I don't know if it's faster. I think it's easier to understand for a novice, which is important. But with more than 2 or 3, it gets very clumsy, which is why I said to use one of the other two solutions in that case.

Answer (score 5):

`any` and generator expressions are your friend:

```
>>> xyz = {"a":{"b":[1,2,3]}}
>>> any(i in xyz.get("a",{}) for i in ["b", "c"])
True
```

Comment: Minor technical point: that's not a list comprehension, it's a generator expression (which is still a kind of comprehension, at least in 3.x, just not the same kind).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects):

```
>>> bool({'b','c'}.intersection(xyz.get('a')))
True
```

the following benchmark shows that its more efficient than `any` :

```
:~$ python -m timeit "xyz = {'a':{'b':[1,2,3]}};any(i in xyz.get('a',{}) for i in ['b', 'c'])"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.932 usec per loop

:~$ python -m timeit "xyz = {'a':{'b':[1,2,3]}};bool({'b','c'}.intersection(xyz.get('a')))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.649 usec per loop
```

But @abarnert's answer in this case is fastest :

```
~$ python -m timeit "xyz = {'a':{'b':[1,2,3]}};'b' in xyz.get('a', {}) or 'c' in xyz.get('a', {})"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.325 usec per loop
```

Comment: I think you need `xyz.get('a', {})`, not `xyz['a']`. He doesn't explain why in his question, but presumably it's for a reason, like the 'a' key doesn't always exist.

Comment: Also, you don't need the `keys` call; a dict is already an Iterable of its keys.

Comment: @abarnert Yes sure fixed!

Comment: @abarnert But about using `get` it has a less performance than indexing! i think its better to use a `try-except` if the performance is very important!

Comment: The performance is almost certainly not important here. Making your code more verbose and more complicated to micro-optimize something that won't matter is for C programmers, not Python. :)

Comment: @abarnert mmm yeah :) but i think this code is more pythonic from python's perspective :P

Comment: Sure, that's why I called your answer "maybe even better"--not because it's faster, but because it's easier to read (and to debug/maintain, since there's less chance to get anything wrong) for anyone who knows what a set is, which seems pretty pythonic to me.

Comment: @abarnert Thank, and i think i need to add the related link to answer!